# Laravel 5.* Availability Calendar

Tags: angularjs, laravel, calendar

Is there any availability calendar for laravel 5.* that allows my users to put their time availability and then shown into a calendar? Should i use vue.js or angular for best performance ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: With all due respect, but just googling "Laravel 5 calendar" gives me at least 4 libraries that do what you want on the first page alone.

Comment: @loek With all due respect , i have not used a calendar before in laravel and i do not know which one is good or bad. Perhaps i am asking someone with experience who has used calendars before and can help me with an example and tell me which one is the best.

Comment: Then your question is a bit generic, it looks like you're just too lazy to google, sorry :) I've got good experience with the spatie/google-calendar lib